# How can I mock the service class in my Controller Test in Micronaut using JUnit5?

Tags: junit5, micronaut

I am writing a `JUnit` test case for the controller in my micronaut application. The controller has a GET endpoint which invokes a method in my service class. I am getting a `NullPointerException` so I am assuming that my service class might not be properly mocked however, I am not sure. I am using `@Mock` (Mockito) for the service.

Am I using the correct annotation to mock the service layer? I have tried to search on google but it hasn't given me much to look into. Thanks.

```
@MicronautTest
public class FPlanControllerTest {

private static final String url = "dummy_url";

@Inject
FPlanService fplanService;

@Inject
@Client("/")
RxHttpClient client;

@Test
public void testGetLayout() {
    FPlanUrl expectedFPlanUrl = new FPlanUrl(url);
    when(fplanService.getLayoutUrl(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenReturn(expectedFPlanUrl);
        FPlanUrl actualFPlanUrl = client.toBlocking()
                .retrieve(HttpRequest.GET("/layout/1000545").header("layoutId", "7"), FPlanUrl.class);
        assertEquals(expectedFPlanUrl , actualFPlanUrl);
    }

@MockBean(FPlanService.class)
    FPlanService fplanService() {
        return mock(FPlanService.class);
    }
}
```

I received the below error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.apartment.controller.FPlanControllerTest.testGetLayout(FPlanControllerTest.java:44)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong. This was giving a `NullPointerException` because the `HTTP` response was expecting a `String` and not the `FPlanUrl` object. The correct code is as below:

```
@Test
public void testGetLayout() {
    FPlanUrl expectedFPlanUrl = new FPlanUrl("http://dummyurl.com");
    when(fplanService.getLayoutUrl(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(expectedFPlanUrl);
    Assertions.assertEquals("{\"url\":\"http://dummyurl.com\"}", client.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.GET("/layout/123").header("layoutId", "7"), String.class);
    verify(fplanService).getLayoutUrl("123","7");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use @MockBean (io.micronaut.test.annotation.MockBean).

Docs - https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#junit5

Comment: I tried '@MockBean' but I received an error that the annotation is disallowed for this location. In the guide, '@MockBean' has been used when the service implements an interface. My service class doesn't implement any interface.

Comment: After correcting the nullpointer exception, I had to use '@MockBean' to inject my service layer as well since it gave me a missing methodInvocationException. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to mock as below :-

```
@MockBean(MyService.class)
MyService myService() {
    return mock(MyService.class);
}
```

Now the service can be injected as:-

```
@Inject
private MyService myService;
```

Use inside your test method as:-

```
@Test
public void myServiceTest() {
    when(myService.foo(any())).thenReturn(any());

    MutableHttpResponse<FooResponse> response = controller.bar(new 
    MyRequest());
    Assertions.assertNotNull(response);
}
```